# How to I open a Bootstrap modal with data fetched from an API in React?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm kinda new to this react thing and I'm starting off my learning process with a admin crud panel for some of my tables. For this question, let's take my table Services for instance, in the Service page there's a list of Services (so I got the read all to work :D) and now I want to be able to click on a user item in the list and it will read all the info of the user from an api and show his info in a modal window.
How can I render the modal and fetch at the same time?

```
    <ul className="list-group">
        {this.state.services.map(service =>
        <li onClick={this.readOneService(service.id)} className="list-group-item" key={service.id}>{service.nom}
            <div className="btn-group btn-group-sm float-right" role="group">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.updateService(service.id)}>Update</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.deleteService(service.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </li>
        )}
    </ul>
```

Here's what I have in my read method:

```
    readOneService(serviceID) {
    // Read all services
    fetch(`/services/${serviceID}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
}
```

Do I have to put a render in there to show my modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting your services from? I guess you fetch them a first time right? Aren't all the information you need in `this.state.services` already?

Because I'd highly recommand that you do fetch the data before, so that you don't do the job 2 times.

I will assume you are using `react-bootstrap` for the exemple:

```
const CustomModal = (service) => (
    <Modal.Dialog>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{service.name}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
            <p>{service.info1}</p>
            <p>{service.info2}</p>
            <p>{service.info3}</p>
        </Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary">Close</Button>
            <Button variant="primary"  onClick={() => this.updateService(service.id)}>Update</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal.Dialog>
);
```

You can also build a function customModal in your component, taking no parameter, and using its state instead.

Then you call it on click trigger as you did it already:

```
// Pass the service metadata
readOneService(service) {
    // Do here whatever you want
    CustomModal(service);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Oh I can use this.state.services to get the service with an id? How can I do this?

Comment: You can use array.prototype.filter function:
`const service = services.filter(item => item.id === id);`
The result will be service[0].

Comment: Your code in the answer doesn't work, it says 'Expecting a new line or a semi colon;

Comment: Erratum: I'm silly, there is a more simple method: `const service = services.find(item => item.id === id);`

Comment: Is this a copy-paste of the error? I checked it and it should work. Oh, the function CustomModal returns some JSX, so make sure to put it inside the render return, between curly braces. Also, be careful to put parenthesis () and not curly braces {} on function declaration.

Comment: I put it in render but now it doesn't work when I reference it from outside

Comment: You either need to import it if you put it in another file, or call this.CustomModal if you declared it inside your component.